# как выбрать из sql уникальные значение

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Есть sql таблица, в которой необходимо сделать выборку таким образом:
Выбрать все поля из таблицы, при условии что name будет уникальным. Как это сделать?
Что-то типа `Select * from users where distinct name;` Но с таким синтаксисом это не работает. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Оконные функции в помощь.  https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-window-functions#:~:text=A%20window%20function%20in%20MySQL,by%20using%20the%20aggregate%20functions.

Comment: Напишите пример для такого запроса пожалуйста.

Comment: Сперва надо чётко определить, что должно быть выведено в остальных полях. Ладно, name уникальный... а дальше? вот одному name соответствует два разных login - какой из них выводить? и выводить ли это поле вообще? Вот это следует чётко определить для каждого поля таблицы. И только потом можно верстать запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Исключительно для MySQL будет работать так

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  users
GROUP BY
  name
```

Если в базе будет более одной записи с повторяющимся `name`, то выведется произвольная запись из этой группы

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть что не для всех MySQL, а в зависимости от настроек, а конкретно ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. И не надо такому учить, чем реньше человек начнет сам задаваться вопросом "а что с остальными колонками", тем лучше